# O que significa "fazer cara de paisagem"?

Tags: significado, expressões

Tenho ouvido essa expressão já há algum tempo e, ao procurar o seu significado encontrei definições divergentes, do tipo:

- "Quando uma pessoa fica extremamente pensativa, com olhar perdido por alguns minutos ou por muito tempo, com alguma preocupação ou pensamento não edificante."
- "Fazer de conta que nada aconteceu. Especialmente se o acontecido teve sua participação."
- "Face inexpressiva, que não demonstra sentimentos nem possíveis reações sobre os factos que se sucedem."

Pelos exemplos acima, fico sem saber se "fazer cara de paisagem" tem um significado preciso ou não.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na minha experiência, "fazer cara de paisagem" significa apenas "**assumir uma expressão neutra**", com conotação que tanto pode ser positiva, quanto negativa.

O segundo significado no OP ("fingir que não é com a pessoa") é um caso particular do terceiro ("ficar inexpressivo, sem esboçar reação"). Esses são os significados que mais associo à expressão. Já a primeira definição ("olhar perdido"), especialmente com a associação com "preocupação ou pensamento não edificante" me parece muito estranha e não creio que já tenha visto.

Segundo um texto publicado na [Folha de São Paulo](https://acervo.folha.com.br/busca.do?keyword=%22cara+de+paisagem%22&periododesc=01%2F01%2F1921+-+01%2F01%2F2000&por=Por+Per%C3%ADodo&startDate=01%2F01%2F1921&endDate=01%2F01%2F2000&days=&month=&year=&jornais=) (30/05/1997; N° 24.894 - Ano 77, Opinião, pg. 2, Marta Salomon) a expressão teria sido popularizada (ao menos na política) pelo então ministro Sérgio Motta:

> Uma das contribuições do ministro Sérgio Motta à política brasileira foi popularizar a expressão "cara de paisagem".
> O termo define um certo ar impávido com que o tucanato tenta administrar a aliança que sustenta Fernando Henrique Cardoso.

Nem o [Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), a [Linguateca](https://www.linguateca.pt/CETENFolha/) ou o [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cara+de+paisagem%22&sxsrf=APq-WBsuRS1ktSreiiWjjues4rc8TIz2YQ%3A1644163302453&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1900%2Ccd_max%3A2000&tbm=) me revelaram um registro anterior.

Answer (score 3):

*"Cara de paisagem"* é um neologismo equivalente a [*"poker face"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_face) e a disseminação da expressão acompanhou a fase ascendente da [moda do poker](https://www.nytimes.com/2008/11/09/fashion/09poker.html) que hoje está em declínio...

Nunca ouvi a expressão em Portugal certamente por a imprensa ser mais resistente a estrangeirismos que não sejam palavras isoladas e quando usa algum termo raramente o traduz do inglês.

Tentei filtrar os resultados do Google por datas para ver a evolução no número de ocorrências da expressão ao longo do tempo mas para esta busca específica as contagens têm números incorentes.

Comment: Também não tive sucesso com o Google, nem muito com os corpus que consultei. O que obtive, de qualquer forma, adicionei à minha resposta.

Comment: @stafusa acho que segue o tipo de expressões muito comuns *"cara de (qualquer coisa)"*, como *"cara de poucos amigos"*, *"cara de pau"*, etc..

Comment: Qual expressão você sugere que acompanhou a fase da "moda do pôquer"? Não consigo ler o artigo, mas a URL diz que é de 2008, e usamos "cara de paisagem" aqui no Brasil há muito mais tempo. Não diria sequer que é um neologismo, muito menos um estrangeirismo. Isso seria se disséssemos "cara de pôquer", não?

Se quer uma expressão bem recente que equivalha a "cara de paisagem" e "poker face", por aqui também dizemos, nos últimos anos, "fazer a egípcia", que seria não só fingir que nada aconteceu, mas ainda virar a cara e olhar para o outro lado, como se não tivesse nada a ver com o ocorrido.